# Добавление в словарь

Tags: python, python-2.x

Привет всем,
Я пытаюсь создать список студентов:

```
first_name = []
source_name = []
dict1 = {}
n = input("How many new students: ")
for i in range(0, n):
   name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
   s_n = raw_input("Enter second name: ")
   first_name.extend([name])
   source_name.extend([s_n])
   dict1['name'] = first_name
   dict1['source_name'] = source_name
print dict1
```

Но почему-то когда я добавлю больше одного студента, у меня появляется только последний студент, которого я добавил. Почему?

Comment: Запустил этот код — добавляются таки все студенты как положено, сформулируйте проблему яснее

Comment: У меня появляется только последний студент которого я добавляю, а первый проподает.

Comment: Объяснили бы (скриншотом, например), как вы определяете, что есть лишь последний студент, ибо я в `print dict1` вижу всех студентов

Comment: Может не правильно себя объяснил, но вроде все работает сейчас, спасибо все равно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохая идея хранить списки имен и фамилий студентов в словаре. Вам нужно просто хранить список словарей и все. Словарь нужен для представления одной сущности, как объект.

```
students = []
n = input("How many new students: ")
for i in range(0, n):
   name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
   s_n = raw_input("Enter second name: ")
   students.append({'name': name, 'source_name': s_n})
print students
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Comment: Решение правильное, а причина проблемы нет, потому что в словарь записываются списки и там по-любому есть все студенты :)

Comment: @andreymal, а ну да, но это плохая идея так делать.